# Javascript PDF binary response to file

Tags: javascript, pdf, stream, buffer, blob

I am getting a PDF binary response from my API, the response looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.3
%ÿÿÿÿ
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 6 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Producer (PDFKit)
/Creator (PDFKit)
/CreationDate (D:20170306125445Z)
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [5 0 R]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 129
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x½
Aû<E^À5Éfó °Øxbwïß¸Å)ÎÀ#nxL(HxÿÂûþæ5Jx®ÒÐ#J²b_`{ÁþËÔHUMo®Bc«Ðéýç?dV{[É½qIoWK»;ÙlíCòç;/'
endstream
endobj
xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000452 00000 n 
0000000403 00000 n 
0000000509 00000 n 
0000000125 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000306 00000 n 
0000000214 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 8
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 7 0 R
>>
startxref
710
%%EOF
```

I am trying to convert this binary response to a PDF file. I googled on how to convert this into Blob and this is what I tried:

```
    var blob = new Blob([this.props.pdfDownloadData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log(downloadUrl);
```

I am getting output as: `blob:http://localhost:3000/9fc4a05e-733b-4d34-94ac-ac76bacfb8e5`. This everytime gives me blank page.

On node server I am using PDFKit, to create PDF and send a stream. This is within react application, and I am getting the response in ajax.

```
let doc = new PDFDocument( {
            size: 'A4',
            margin: 50
        } );
        doc.pipe(res);
        doc.compress = false;

        doc.fontSize( 32 );

        doc.text( 'PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {
            align: 'center',
            width: 200
        } );
        doc.end();
```

Comment: Well, the included PDF *is* a blank PDF document. Also, you can specify the response to be of type blob without the need to convert it to one. I don't known the PDFKit, but I guess you probably need to flush the stream (or wait for it to finish) to actually be able to grab the changes.